How to implement tikz in tabular in tikz
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                every node/.style={align=center},
                ent/.style={text width=2.5cm},
            ]
            \node[ent,](prover){\Large\textbf{Prover}};
            \node[ent,right=2cm of prover](verifier){\Large\textbf{Verifier}};
            \node[below=.5cm of verifier](CRP){
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    Challenge                                                                         & Response                                                                          \\\hline
                    \(c_1\)                                                                           & \(r_1\)                                                                           \\\hline
                    \(c_2\) & \(r_2\) \\\hline
                    \(\vdots\)                                                                        & \(\vdots\)                                                                        \\\hline
                    \(c_n\)                                                                           & \(r_n\)                                                                           \\\hline
                \end{tabular}
            };
            \node[ent]at(CRP-|prover)(PUF){\(r_2'=\mathtt{PUF}({c_2})\)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}

How should I do implement as follows?


This is what the \subnode commmand from the tikzmark library was designed to do: put a pseudo-node around some content that is itself within a \node. Nesting tikzpictures - even putting a \tikzmarknode inside a \node - can go horribly wrong and so is definitely Not Recommended. But \subnode doesn't nest tikzpictures so avoids that unpleasantness.
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732522/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  tikzmark, % needed for `\subnode`
  fit, % needed for the circles
  arrows.meta, % nicer arrows
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={align=center},
  ent/.style={text width=2.5cm},
  remember picture, % needed to make `\subnode` work
  >=Latex % nicer arrows
]
\node[ent,](prover){\Large\textbf{Prover}};
\node[ent,right=2cm of prover](verifier){\Large\textbf{Verifier}};
\node[below=.5cm of verifier](CRP){
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  Challenge & Response \\\hline
  \(c_1\)& \(r_1\)\\\hline
  \subnode{c2-b}{\(c_2\)} & \subnode{r2-b}{\(r_2\)} \\\hline % `\subnode`s here
  \(\vdots\)& \(\vdots\)\\\hline
  \(c_n\)& \(r_n\)\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
};
\node[ent]at(CRP-|prover)(PUF){\(\subnode{r2-a}{r_2'}=\mathtt{PUF}(\subnode{c2-a}{c_2})\)}; % more `\subnodes`
\node[red,below=1cm of CRP,draw] (CMP) {CMP}; % this is part of the drawing
% Put circles around the key nodes
\node[red,fit=(r2-a),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (r2-ac) {};
\node[red,fit=(r2-b),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (r2-bc) {};
\node[red,fit=(c2-a),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (c2-ac) {};
\node[red,fit=(c2-b),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (c2-bc) {};
% Draw the arrows
\draw[red,->] (r2-ac) to[out=-90,in=180] (CMP);
\draw[red,<-] (CMP) to[out=0,in=-45] (r2-bc);
\draw[red,->] (c2-bc) to[out=135,in=45] (c2-ac);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You are right. (+1). I forgot on the subnode option.

@Zarko It's an easy one to forget - its use is quite specialised.

Based on my answer on your previous question without use of saveboxes:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                tikzmark}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 11mm,
   ent/.style = {text width=23mm, align=center, font=\Large\bfseries},
   box/.style = {fill=magenta!30},
   bend angle = 45,
every tikzmarknode/.style = {draw=red, rounded corners, 
                             minimum height=3ex, inner sep=2pt},
%   
remember picture,
            ]
\node[ent]                  (prover)    {Prover};
\node[ent,right=of prover]  (verifier)  {Verifier};
\node[below=of verifier]    (tab)       {
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec= {Q[c, m] Q[c, m]}
                 }
        Challenge   &   Response    \\
        \(c_1\)     &   \(r_1\)     \\
        \tikzmarknode{a}{\(c_2\)}
                    &   \tikzmarknode{b}{\(r_2\)}
                                    \\
        \(\vdots\)  &   \(\vdots\)  \\
        \(c_n\)     &   \(r_n\)     \\
    \end{tblr}
                                };
\node   at (a -| prover)    (PUF) 
    {\(\tikzmarknode{c}{r_2'}=\mathtt{PUF}({\tikzmarknode{d}{c_2}})\)};
\node[draw, below=of tab] (e) {CMP};
\draw[-Stealth, red]    (a)      edge[bend right] (d)
                        (b)      edge[bend  left] (e.east)
                        (c.south) to [bend right=30] (e.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

After three compilation of above MWE you will get:

Edit:
Above solution works fine, but by accident (so far I haven't problems with use \tikzmarknode inside nodes in a tikzpicture, but anyway they can happens). Correct approach is to use \subnode as is suggested in  answer of @Andrew Stacey.
Unfortunately \subnode not support (yet) drawing border around it. Due to this you need to define additional nodes with fit options which draw borders around \subnodes.
Just for exercise below is MWE based in my original suggestion but consider use of \subnodes:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,    % for drawing nborder of subnodes
                positioning,
                tikzmark}
\usepackage{tabularray}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 11mm,
   ent/.style = {text width=23mm, align=center, font=\Large\bfseries},
   box/.style = {fill=magenta!30},
   bend angle = 45,
%
    sn/.style = {draw=red, rounded corners,
                 inner xsep=-2pt, inner ysep=0pt, 
                 fit=(#1), node contents={}},
remember picture,
                        ]
\node[ent]                  (prover)    {Prover};
\node[ent,right=of prover]  (verifier)  {Verifier};
\node[below=of verifier]    (tab)       {
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec= {Q[c, m] Q[c, m]},
                 row{3} = {belowsep=4pt}
                 }
        Challenge   &   Response    \\
        \(c_1\)     &   \(r_1\)     \\
        \subnode{A}{\(c_2\)}
                    &   \subnode{B}{\(r_2\)}
                                    \\
        \(\vdots\)  &   \(\vdots\)  \\
        \(c_n\)     &   \(r_n\)     \\
    \end{tblr}
                                };
\node   at (A -| prover)    (PUF)
    {\(\subnode{C}{r_2'}=\mathtt{PUF}(\,\subnode{D}{c_2}\,)\)};
\node[draw, below=of tab] (E) {CMP};
\% Put circles around the key nodes
\node (a) [sn=A];  
\node (b) [sn=B];     
\node (c) [sn=C];
\node (d) [sn=D];
%
\draw[-Stealth, red]    (a)      edge[bend right] (d)
                        (b)      edge[bend  left] (E.east)
                        (c.south) to [out=270,in=180] (E.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you for your advice.
If I want to change the decoration for each tikzmarknode,  what should I do?

@KokiMIZOGUCHI, define desired style in every tikzmarknode/.style or in sn/.style in my second example. I strongly encourage to use accepted answer, or if you liked, my second answer added in edit.

I was able to find a solution by incorporating the savebox idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732342/319072, and the  \tikzmarknode idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731625/319072.
Hopefully there is a way to do it without saveboxes though, because each one requires a unique name.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newsavebox{\tempboxtwo}
\newsavebox{\tempboxthree}
\tikzset{
  every tikzmarknode/.style={fill=white,draw=red,thin,inner sep=2pt,rounded corners=5pt}
}
\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Challenge                                                                         & Response                                                                          \\\hline
    \(c_1\)                                                                           & \(r_1\)                                                                           \\\hline
    \(\tikzmarknode{a-1}{c_2}\) & \(\tikzmarknode{a-2}{r_2}\) \\\hline
    \(\vdots\)                                                                        & \(\vdots\)                                                                        \\\hline
    \(c_n\)                                                                           & \(r_n\)                                                                           \\\hline
\end{tabular}}

\savebox{\tempboxtwo}{%
\(\tikzmarknode{a-4}{r_2'}=\mathtt{PUF}({\tikzmarknode{a-3}{c_2}})\)}

\savebox{\tempboxthree}{%
\tikzmarknode[rounded corners=0pt]{a-5}{{\color{red}CmP}}}
                
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={align=center},
        ent/.style={text width=2.5cm},
    ]
    \node[ent,](prover){\Large\textbf{Prover}};
    \node[ent,right=2cm of prover](verifier){\Large\textbf{Verifier}};
    \node[below=.5cm of verifier](CRP){\usebox\tempbox};
    \node[ent]at(CRP-|prover)(PUF){\usebox\tempboxtwo};
    \node[below=.5cm of CRP]{\usebox\tempboxthree};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,->,shorten <=-2pt] (a-1) to[out=140,in=75] (a-3);
\draw[red,->] (a-2) to[out=0,in=0] (a-5);
\draw[red,->] (a-4) to[out=270,in=180] (a-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


