Why is the figure going out of shape with `uplatex` and `dvipdfmx`?
The following source code follows as the question.
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{jsarticle}
% Compile: uplatex -> uplatex -> dvipdfmx
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732522/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  tikzmark, % needed for `\subnode`
  fit, % needed for the circles
  arrows.meta, % nicer arrows
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={align=center},
  ent/.style={text width=2.5cm},
  remember picture, % needed to make `\subnode` work
  >=Latex % nicer arrows
]
\node[ent,](prover){\Large\textbf{Prover}};
\node[ent,right=2cm of prover](verifier){\Large\textbf{Verifier}};
\node[below=.5cm of verifier](CRP){
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  Challenge & Response \\\hline
  \(c_1\)& \(r_1\)\\\hline
  \subnode{c2-b}{\(c_2\)} & \subnode{r2-b}{\(r_2\)} \\\hline % `\subnode`s here
  \(\vdots\)& \(\vdots\)\\\hline
  \(c_n\)& \(r_n\)\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
};
\node[ent]at(CRP-|prover)(PUF){\(\subnode{r2-a}{r_2'}=\mathtt{PUF}(\subnode{c2-a}{c_2})\)}; % more `\subnodes`
\node[red,below=1cm of CRP,draw] (CMP) {CMP}; % this is part of the drawing
% Put circles around the key nodes
\node[red,fit=(r2-a),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (r2-ac) {};
\node[red,fit=(r2-b),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (r2-bc) {};
\node[red,fit=(c2-a),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (c2-ac) {};
\node[red,fit=(c2-b),draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] (c2-bc) {};
% Draw the arrows
\draw[red,->] (r2-ac) to[out=-90,in=180] (CMP);
\draw[red,<-] (CMP) to[out=0,in=-45] (r2-bc);
\draw[red,->] (c2-bc) to[out=135,in=45] (c2-ac);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



is pgf support for dvipdfmx documented anywhere? it doesn't seem to be in the obvious place in the manual. but, in general, drivers involving dvi tend to be less well supported than those producing pdf directly. I don't know why the manual doesn't mention this one. still, I'd expect it to be similar to dvipdfm or xdvipdfmx, which should support remember.

I think @cfr is right. I think that pipelines which don't go straight to pdf are not compatible with remembering locations on the page.

@AndrewStacey the driver does support remember picture, though. I tried a basic case involving no libraries and just current page anchors and that seems to work OK even with overlay and page content. (I'm not sure if everything works, but something works.) and this isn't mentioned as unsupported for dvipdfm/xdvipdfmx, even though not-remembering is listed as unsupported for some other drivers. so I think the problem is a bit more nuanced. there's a subtler inconsistency somewhere.

@cfr Interestingly, when I compile the above with lualatex (changing jsarticle to article) then I get the error: Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def does not support marking the current position. This warning is given only once on input line 26. That suggests that dvipdfmx doesn't do the remember picture properly. I don't know why that isn't getting triggered by uplatex.

@AndrewStacey latex doesn't seem to generate the warning either. I get a different wrong result with lualatex ....

@AndrewStacey it seems there's something quite specific about dvipdfmx + lualatex as opposed to dvipdfmx + latex?

@cfr Quite possibly, I also don't get a warning with xelatex but get a different wrong result (though quite similar to uplatex) and I know that xelatex doesn't work well with remember picture. I wonder what engine uplatex is based on.

@AndrewStacey it's strange because the manual mentions this problem for some drivers, but doesn't mention it for others, even though it seems to be problematic there, too. in some cases, it looks as if it remembers something, but the location is systematically wrong?
